# How to properly stop ASP.NET registered object factory

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Short question:**

Should I un-register a "factory" [`IRegisteredObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject(v=vs.110).aspx) in [`IRegisteredObject.Stop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) if `immediate` is false?

**Painfully long version:**

Sometimes in an ASP.NET app, you want to ["fire and forget"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) a background process.

IIS occasionally recycles ASP.NET apps. If you simply fire off a `Task.Run`, [your background process will disappear](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) when the recycle happens.

To mitigate disappearing background work, you implement `IRegisteredObject` and register it so ASP.NET can provide your background work fair warning before recycling.

ASP.NET [will only register one `IRegisteredObject` of a given type at any given time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223297(v=vs.110).aspx). So to handle multiple `IRegisteredObject`s of the same type, you must implement a "factory" `IRegisteredObject` to manage the queue.

Here is my rephrasing of [MSDN's example factory `IRegisteredObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223297(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Factory : IRegisteredObject 
{
    private List<Work> workItems = new List<Work>;

    public void Start()
    {
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
    }

    void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        foreach (Work w in workItems)
        {
            // Inform each work item ASP.NET has to recycle.
            w.Stop(immediate);
        }

        // Unregister this factory object.
        // Should we do this if !immediate ???
        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }

    public AddWork(Work w)
    {
        w.Init();
        workItems.Add(w);
        return w;
    }
}

public class Work : IRegisteredObject
{
    void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        // If not immediate, start wrapping up.
        // If immediate, wrap up quickly.
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        // Do things to start working.
    }
}
```

In Factory.Stop, the Factory `IRegisteredObject` will be un-registered after the `Work` items have received the first (non-`immediate`) "stopping" message.

Shouldn't we wait to un-register until `immediate == true`, so that ASP.NET will still be aware that some work may still be underway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must not. That is why you can get a call with Immediate==true.
So if you still have some work to do, you can leave it registered

Comment: In other words the MSDN example isn't (completely) correct, and I should wrap `UnregisterObject` in `if (immediate)`?

Comment: I was answering the short version of the question, which seems to be opposite of the question at the end of the long version. For the long version question: Unregister when the work is done, do not postpone until immediate==true

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how I managed to ask the same question in opposite-sounding ways. Thanks for the clarification!